# Unparseable date Exception while trying to format date with the format "2018-07-30T12:31:02"

Tags: android

I am trying to format date from server with the following code

```
 private SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa", Locale.getDefault());
 try {

            Date dtShiftDate = format.parse(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("shiftdetails_ShiftStartTime"))); 
            Date dtCurrDate = format.parse(strCurrDate);
            if (dtShiftDate.getTime() != dtCurrDate.getTime()) {
                bLastShiftNotEnded = true;
            }
        } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
            Log.e("Date parse exception",e.getMessage());
        }
```

am getting Unparceable Exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is something wrong either with the String you are providing to
>   the parse() method, or with the Format you are providing. You should
>   check again carefully both of these aspects, and of course develop a
>   range of tests that confirm the correctness of your Format.

Your logcat throws

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date:
```

- You should rectify your [**`SimpleDateFormat`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat) format.

Try with

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
```

**FYI**

```
h   Hour in am/pm (1-12)
H   Hour in day (0-23)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your format to this "yyyy/MM/dd'T'HH:mm:ss"